# Parsing JSON to do math?

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x, string, math

I'm new to programming (especially JSON format), so please forgive me not for using proper terminology :)
Using Python 3.7 Requests module, I receive a JSON response. To keep things simple, I made an example:

```
{
    "Bob":
  {
  "Age": "15",
  "LastExamGrade": "45",
  },

    "Jack":
  {
  "Age": "16",
  "LastExamGrade": "58",
  }
}
```

What I would like to do is parse the JSON responses to extract two items from each response/structure and save it to a list like this (I think this is called a tuple of tuples?):

```
[("Bob","45"),("Jack","58")]
```

Then, after receiving doing this, I will receive another similar response, such as the following (where the only thing that changed is the exam grade):

```
{
    "Bob":
  {
  "Age": "15",
  "LastExamGrade": "54",
  },

    "Jack":
  {
  "Age": "16",
  "LastExamGrade": "70",
  }
}
```

I want to also save the name and grade into a tuple of tuples (list).

Lastly, I would like to subtract the first exam score of each person from their last exam score, and save this into a final list, which includes the name, final exam grade, and grade improvement, like this:

```
[("Bob","54","9"),("Jack","67","12")]
```

What is the simplest way to do this using Python 3? As for my own research, I've searched all throughout StackOverflow, but couldn't find out how to parse a JSON like mine (For example, in mine, the name is outside of the curly braces), and had difficulty doing math operations for JSON items.

Comment: You need to learn about *dictionaries*.

Comment: @ScottHunter Hi, thanks for the reply. I have a little bit of knowledge of what dictionaries are, but I'm not really familiar with how to use them to do what I'm trying to do. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using a dedicated package for calculations like pandas:

```
first_exam_grades = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(first_exam_results, orient='index').astype(int)
second_exam_grades = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(second_exam_results, orient='index').astype(int)
improvements = second_exam_grades.LastExamGrade.to_frame()
improvements['Improvement'] = second_exam_grades.LastExamGrade - first_exam_grades.LastExamGrade
```

This will give you something that looks like this:

[image]

Now you can output it anyway you'd like

```
list(zip(*([improvements.index.tolist()] + [improvements[c].values.tolist() for c in improvements])))
```

This will give you `[('Bob', 54, 9), ('Jack', 70, 12)]` as you want.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution, using *coroutines*. Coroutine `receive_message` holds up to last two values `LastExamGrade` from the message for each student and produces list of student name, last grade and improvement over last grade:

```
json_messages = [
# 1st message:
{
   "Bob":
  {
  "Age": "15",
  "LastExamGrade": "45",
  },

    "Jack":
  {
  "Age": "16",
  "LastExamGrade": "58",
  }
},
# 2nd message
{
    "Bob":
  {
  "Age": "15",
  "LastExamGrade": "54",
  },

    "Jack":
  {
  "Age": "16",
  "LastExamGrade": "70",
  }
},
# 3nd message (optional)
{
    "Bob":
  {
  "Age": "15",
  "LastExamGrade": "14",
  },

    "Jack":
  {
  "Age": "16",
  "LastExamGrade": "20",
  }
}
]

def receive_message():
    d, message = {}, (yield)
    while True:
        for k, v in message.items():
            d.setdefault(k, []).append(v['LastExamGrade'])
            d[k] = d[k][-2:] # store max last two messages
        message = yield [(k, *tuple(v if len(v)==1 else [v[1], str(int(v[1])-int(v[0]))])) for k, v in d.items()]

receiver = receive_message()
next(receiver) # prime coroutine

for msg in json_messages:
    print(receiver.send(msg))
```

Prints:

```
[('Bob', '45'), ('Jack', '58')]
[('Bob', '54', '9'), ('Jack', '70', '12')]
[('Bob', '14', '-40'), ('Jack', '20', '-50')]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I found Alex's answer a little bit simpler, but yours works too!